# Gaping b/w the Navbar and Content bar ,Cant find the issue after a little debugging

Tags: css

[image: Image of the resultant template]

Hi, i wanted to ask that im not getting that why is that a marginal space b/w the navbar and the content box i double checked the tried some debugging using chrome but still dint found the de thats causing this error..the code is below:

```css
/*css code*/
    #header{
    
        height: 85px;
        padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: cyan;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        
    }
    body{
        background-image: url(gods_of_egypt_elodie_yung-3840x2160.jpg);
     background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
     
    }
    #heading{
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 70px;
    
        text-align: center;
     margin: 0px;
    }
    #navbar{
     
        background-color: grey;
        margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
     height: 30px;
     overflow: hidden
    
      
    }
    ul{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
     font-family: arial;
    }
    li{
     display: inline;
    }
    a{
     display: block;
        text-align: center;
     float: left;
     width: 100px;
     padding: 3px;
     line-height: 25px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
     margin-top: 0px;
    }
    a:hover{
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
     color: black;
    }
    /*
    #searchbar{
     
     margin-left: 250px;
     margin-top: 4px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
    }*/
    #content{
     background-color: white;
     height: 400px;
     margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
    }
```

```html
     <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <body>
    
    
        <div id="header">
            <h1 id="heading">#Some Stuff</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
     <p>WOW!
     </p>
     </content> 
     
     </body>
    </html>
```

please help fix this issue cause im totally clueless for why im stuck here

Comment: Just to note, you have ended your div id=content with </content> instead of </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUICK:

```
#content p
{
    margin:0px;
}
```

EXPLANATION

By default, some browsers put an automatic margin to tags.

For instance for body

```
margin: 8px;
```

On the < body> tag. In your code you can simply add:

```
body {
     background-image: url(gods_of_egypt_elodie_yung-3840x2160.jpg);
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;

     margin: 0px; //THIS LINE HERE!
     }
```

It make the same also for  tag

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

SO, also there you can force a

```
 margin:0px;
```